# NameError with a Many to Many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nameerror

I'm trying to add a Join/Unjoin button to user created Events, similar to a Follow/Unfollow button for Users.

I'm not sure what to define @rsvps as in the event#show

NameError in Events#show
undefined local variable or method `event' for #<#:0x007f9dfaf9d978>

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Join Event", rsvps_path(:event_id => event), :method => :post %>
```

events_controller.rb

```
def show
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @user = current_user
  #@rsvp = ???? something here ????
end
```

rsvps_controller.rb

```
class RsvpsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create
    @rsvp = current_user.rsvps.build(:event_id => params[:event_id])
    if @rsvp.save
      flash[:notice] = "Joined event."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to join event."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @rsvp = current_user.rsvps.find(params[:id])
    @rsvp.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Unjoin Event."
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

Here are the models

rsvp.rb

```
class Rsvp < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :event_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :rsvps
has_many :events, through: :rsvps, dependent: :destroy
```

event.rb

```
belongs_to :user

has_many :rsvps
has_many :users, through: :rsvps, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code would be more rails-ish.

```
# user.rb
has_many :users_events
has_many :events, through: :users_events

# event.rb
has_many :users_events
has_many :users, through: :users_events

# users_event.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event
```

ActiveRecord do everything else. 8)

For example `user.events` and `event.users` methods.

Join and unjoin to user actions may be processed by `events controller`. Update method can look like this

```
# events_controller.rb
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event.users << current_user if params[:action] == 'join'
    @event.users.delete(current_user) if params[:action] == 'unjoin' 
    if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
      format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

A little bit messy, but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: hmmm much simpler than i thought lol. so would i just need to create a method for rsvps for a user to join or unjoin an event?  sorry if its a basic question kinda new to rails

Comment: No. You should already have `update` method in your `events_controller`. So you can `PUT` there some data to join/unjoin it to user. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Oh, one more. I think that I didn't understand correct from first time. Event can have more than one user, right? If so, you'll **need** join model and my answer really sucks.

Comment: haha ahh sorry man yeah the events do have multiple users that join

Comment: Oh, shi~! I've adopted my answer to this situation. 8)

Answer (score 0):

Your undefined local variable or method error seems to be coming from trying to pass `:event_id => event` to your controller through rsvp_path. Instead you should just be passing the event object like so

```
<%= link_to "Join Event", rsvps_path(event), :method => :post %>
```

the line `@event = Event.find(params[:id])` in your controller will take care of figuring out what event you passed to it.